# Receber múltiplas strings na mesma linha em C

Tags: c, array, string, alocação, entrada-de-dados

Eu possuo o seguinte código que obtém a entrada do teclado e imprime na tela o que foi digitado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

  char *name = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));
  char *city = malloc(50 * sizeof(char));

  fgets(name, 50, stdin);
  fgets(city, 50, stdin);

  printf("%s %s",name,city);

  free(name);
  free(city);

  return 0;
```

Quando tento digitar um nome seguido de uma cidade, ocorrem quebras de linhas a cada string que eu tento

Comportamento ocorrido no console:

```
João da Silva,
Campinas
```

Comportamento esperado:

```
João da Silva, Campinas
```

Minha dúvida é entender o por que meu código se comporta dessa maneira (por que a quebra de linha após as entradas ocorre) e como eu faria para fazer essas entradas (precisam ser variáveis diferentes) na mesma linha, sem que eu precise quebrar a linha para tal.

Comment: Qual o sentido de você alocar memória para armazenar 5 caracteres e logo depois utilizar a função fgets para ler até 200 caracteres? Não entendi qual é o intuito de você utilizar este gaetchar. A definição da função fgets diz que ela irá ler caracteres até encontrar um '\n' ou o número máximo de caracteres especificado na função. Veja: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgets.html

Comment: No caso como sou iniciante, alguns critérios ainda não são claros pra mim, eu provavelmente deveria, ao invés de colocar 200, 5*sizeof no fgets. Postei minha dúvida aqui para fins de aprendizado mesmo e ser instruído. Obrigado pelo link, irei lê-lo.

Comment: Outro ponto a considerar é `name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';`. O objetivo é substituir o caractere '\n' que foi incorporado ao final da string lida pela função fgets pelao caractere '\0' que indica o final da string, contudo caso a string na entrada seja maior que o tamanho especificado (200 no seu caso) este caractere '\n' não existirá em sua string. O melhor seria você verificar se o último caractere é '\n' e se for então substitui-lo pelo '\0'.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Usando a função fgets() você sempre terá uma nova linha entre os itens pois ela sempre adiciona '\n' no console ao apertar enter no teclado.

Para obter o comportamento desejado, você pode usar a função scanf() e o caracter ',' para separar as duas strings.

Veja o código de exemplo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {

  char *name = malloc(200 * sizeof(char));
  char *city = malloc(200 * sizeof(char));

  scanf("%200[^,]s",name);
  scanf("%200[^\n]s",city);

  printf("%s%s",name,city);

  free(name);
  free(city);

  return 0;
}
```

Assim, o primeiro scanf vai inserir na variável name todos os caracteres que você digitar até encontrar o caracter ',' (com '\0' no final). O segundo scanf vai inserir na variável city todos os caracteres até encontrar o caracter '\n', inserindo '\0' ao final. Sendo assim você poderia digitar: João da Silva, Campinas [enter] para atribuir as strings em uma mesma linha.

Repare no primeiro parâmetro da função scanf():
"%200[^,]s"
**200** representa a quantidade máxima de caracteres (tem de estar compatível com o tamanho do seu vetor de char), **[^,]** representa que a string será encerrada ao se encontrar o caracter ',' na entrada padrão e **s** representa o tipo de dados lido, no caso uma string.

Comment: Thiago, obrigado pelas pontuações, consegui fazer a correção necessária no código e de fato o resultado foi melhor. Sobre a última parte da minha pergunta, vou pedir sua ajuda novamente. Entendo sobre como fazer o laço para a repetição acontecer, mas não saberia como fazer a entrada de dados na mesma linha. Por exemplo: João da Silva. Campinas. Isso ainda me foge a capacidade.

Comment: Olá Guilherme, atualizei a resposta para lhe dar um caminho sobre inserir os dados na mesma linha. Você não conseguirá obter o mesmo resultado usando fgets() pois este insere automaticamente um '\n' e haverá um salto de linha.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava Tiago, obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

Não há necessidade de utilizar alocação dinâmica pro teu programa, já que o valor é constante e mesmo que decida por continuar utilizando alocação dinâmica, definir constantes é uma prática recomendável para reduzir a probabilidade de erros futuros.

```
int main(void) {
   const int TAMANHO = 200;

   char *name = malloc(TAMANHO * sizeof(char));
   char *city = malloc(TAMANHO * sizeof(char));

   // Você pode trocar as duas linhas acima pela alocação estática abaixo:
   //char name[TAMANHO], city[TAMANHO]; 

   fgets(name, TAMANHO, stdin);
   name[strlen(name) - 1] = '\0';
   
   fgets(city, TAMANHO, stdin);
   city[strlen(city) - 1] = '\0';
   
   //Você também pode imprimir o que deseja com apenas uma chamada da função printf
   printf("%s %s\n",name, city);

   //Caso aloque estaticamente você pode eliminar os frees abaixo
   free(name);
   free(city);
   return 0;
}
```

A função getchar lê um caractere e pode ser utilizada para que o '\n' que é deixado no buffer de entrada não interfira na leitura de strings ou caracteres subsequentes. No seu exemplo não há necessidade de utilizá-la porque a função fgets já lê esse '\n' e insere na string (que você já está tratando com o comando imediatamente posterior a leitura).